# why am i getting different response to similar ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

`issue resolved, see edit : both the php scripts are returning json_encode()'d 2D arrays, but one response(trains) is received as a multidimensional array and the other(data) as an object, why is this happening?`

secondly the line console.log(data) was executed after console.log(allData), shouldn't it be the other way round ??, i need to populate allData with responses contained in data. Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").submit(function(){    
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      //type: "POST",
      url: "./trains_bw_stations.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { source: $('input[name*="src"]').val(), destination: $('input[name*="dstn"]').val(), 
                day: $('input[name*="day"]').val(), month: $('input[name*="month"]').val(), cl: $('input[name*="cl"]').val()  }
    })
      .done(function(trains) {
        console.log(trains)
        var requests = [], allData = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
            console.log(trains[i][0]);
            requests.push($.ajax({
                url: './availability.php', 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                        day: $('input[name*="day"]').val(), month: $('input[name*="month"]').val(),lccp_trndtl: trains[i][0]  }
                // success: function(data) {
                //  console.log(data);
                //     allData[''+i] = data;

            }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    allData[i] = data})
            );
        }

        $.when.apply(requests).then(function() {

            console.log(allData)
        for (var i in allData) {
          if (allData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            console.log(i+ " -> " + allData[i])
              }
            }
            // all requests have completed
            // allData array now contains the data from all the requests
            // put your processing logic in here...
        });
    });

});
});
```

copy pasted console output, it shows line 41 executing before 34 :

```
[Array[15], Array[15], Array[15]] ajaxRequests.js:19
12650NZM KCG NYYNYNYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
12724NDLSHYB NYYYYYYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
12722NZM HYB YYYYYYYYA ajaxRequests.js:23
Object {} ajaxRequests.js:41
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
 ajaxRequests.js:34
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
 ajaxRequests.js:34
Object {0: Array[4], 2: Array[4], 4: Array[4], 6: Array[4], 8: Array[4], 10: Array[4]}
 ajaxRequests.js:34
```

**EDIT:**
I think i Understand the reason the first issue is occuring :response of first request is enclosed in a [], and hence percieved as an array

```
[["12650NZM KCG YYYNYNYYA","12650"," +KTK SMPRK K EXP ","H NIZAMUDDIN ","06:45","KACHEGUDA ","07:05","24:20","Y","Y","N","Y","N","Y","Y"],["12724NDLSHYB NYYYYYYYA","12724"," +A P EXPRESS  ","NEW DELHI ","17:30","HYDERABAD DECAN","19:50","26:20","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"],["12722NZM HYB YYYYYYYYA","12722"," +DAKSHIN EXPRESS ","H NIZAMUDDIN ","23:00","HYDERABAD DECAN","05:00","30:00","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"]]
```

Second type of requests' responses are enclosed in {} :

```
{"0":[" 1"," 7- 8-2014","AVAILABLE 28","AVAILABLE 12"],"2":[" 2"," 9- 8-2014","RAC24\/RAC 22 ","GNWL25\/WL20"],"4":[" 3","10- 8-2014","AVAILABLE 127","AVAILABLE 35"],"6":[" 4","11- 8-2014","AVAILABLE 179","AVAILABLE 56"],"8":[" 5","12- 8-2014","AVAILABLE 143","RAC2\/RAC 2 "],"10":[" 6","14- 8-2014","AVAILABLE 39","GNWL25\/WL9"]}
```

I don't know why that is yet, since json_encode() is acting on 2D array in both cases(constructed by traversing over DOMNodeList, if that helps anyone make sense of it), but at least I know now why JS is treating them differently.
Still have no idea as to the second question though.

**EDIT 2 :**Ok, so one is encoded from an associative array I think, that is what is causing the problem., still don't have an answer to the second question

Comment: Open the AJAX request URL in the browser and see if it is really the same format (posting here could help too). That way you can isolate whether this is happening on the client-side (code above) or the server-side (PHP).

Comment: See example 3. http://php.net/json_encode  Your second example is non-sequential, your first example is sequential.

Comment: yeah, I understand that now. The second question is still bugging me.

Comment: @EagerNoob I don't even know what your second question is asking, could you try to explain it better?

Comment: the line of code in the done function of ajax requests being pushed into the array seems to be executing after $.when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP arrays can either be encoded as JS arrays or JS objects. If, and only if, the array's key are all numeric, and in order, and starting from zero, and without any missing (you are missing odd-numbered keys) then it will be an array. Otherwise ("sparse" arrays) it will be an object.

---

For your second question, I'm not sure because I don't use jQuery :p But here's how I'd handle a "when all ajax stuff is done" bit of code:

```
var count = trains.length;
for (var i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
    console.log(trains[i][0]);
    requests.push($.ajax({
        url: './availability.php', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            day: $('input[name*="day"]').val(),
            month: $('input[name*="month"]').val(),
            lccp_trndtl: trains[i][0]
        }
     }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            allData[i] = data;
            count--;
            if( count == 0) doSomethingElse(allData);
     });
}

// replace that `when.apply` thing with `doSomethingElse` definition
```

Comment: yes, that answers my first question perfectly, can you have a look into the second issue ?

Comment: on a side note..pokefarm !! you can't battle, can you ? I'm not much for breeding pokemon :S

Comment: @EagerNoob See my edit :) And no, PFQ does not have battling - so barbaric :p

Comment: I guess that the second question is an entirely different issue from the first and I should remove it from the question itself !

Comment: it is being handled in a separate question anyway, should I edit it out of the question now ? To make this one more concise and coherent ?